# TemplateDoesNotExist at

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have a problem with REQUEST.

Add `myapp`, so that it recognizes the parameters in `request`, however, it keeps throwing me an error when reloading the page. What is the problem?
[Ilustration of problem in WEB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koJuX.png)
[CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAG2w.png)

[Second problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04iyG.png)
def index(request):

```
def index(request):

html= """
    <h1>Inicio</h1>
    <p>Años hasta 2050:</p>
    <ul>
"""
year =2021
while year<=2050:

    if year%2 == 0:

        html+=f"<li>{str(year)}</li>"
    year+=1
html +="</ul>"
#return HttpResponse(layout + html)
return render(request, 'index.html')
```

(Index function)

Comment: Do you have a file named `index.html` in your [`TEMPLATE.DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#dirs) ?

Comment: Yes, I have!!!!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#configuration

Answer (score 0):

Inside settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'your_app_name','templates', 'your_app_name'),
                
                ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Ok, agree, add your advice in settings, but there is a problem with: AttributeError at /inicio/
'dict' object has no attribute 'rsplit', which the problem?

Comment: Puedes poner otra imagen?

Comment: Listo, ya está la foto [3]

Comment: Parece ser un problema sin relacion a este, es mejor que abras un problema nuevo :)